# JPQL запрос поиска

Tags: sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

1. Есть такой кастомный метод в репозитории

   ```
   @Query(value = "select b from User b where b.name like :name")
   List<User> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
   ```

   Поиск по имени работает, но только при полном совпадении запроса и имени, как сделать что бы искал даже совпадения? вхождения?
   Пробовал так `'%:name%'` , вылетает ошибка в браузере при поиске

   > org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
2. Почему не работает такая запись запроса?

   ```
   @Query(value = "select b from User b where b.name like ?1")
   List<User> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
   ```

   то есть через указание номера параметра? Вылетает ошибка при деплое:

   > org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.sprhib.service.UserService com.sprhib.controller.UserController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.sprhib.dao.UserDAO.findByName(java.lang.String) but parameter 'name' not found in annotated query 'select b from User b where b.name like ?1'!

Answer (score 1):

Итак ответ на первый вопрос нагуглил.

```
@Query(value = "select b from User b where b.name like concat('%', :name, '%') ")
    List<User> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

А на второй нет(

Comment: Так во втором же случае у вас нет именованного параметра в запросе, а вы его туда пытаетесь передать.